# How to save a php page output in pdf as image

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to save a php output page as pdf through javascript.

```
function createPDF() {
  getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
      doc = new jsPDF({
        unit: 'px',
        format: 'a4',
        orientation: 'L',
      });
    doc.context2d.pageWrapY = doc.internal.pageSize.height - 20;
    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);

    doc.save(s_deal_id + '_booster-report.pdf');
    form.width(cache_width);
  });
}

// create canvas object
function getCanvas() {
  form.width(a4[0] * 1.33333 - 80).css('max-width', 'none');
  return html2canvas(form, {
    imageTimeout: 2000,
    removeContainer: true,
  });
}
```

It's capturing the first page only.
I need the whole page to be saved in pdf.